# During battle can I play a one-shot card?

Tags: munchkin

If combat has started and the other players start discussing what to do to me can I play a one-shot card while they are discussing?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, go right ahead. For most one-shots, the only requirement for playing them is that there's combat happening. As soon as it is, you can play your one-shots. You don't need to wait your turn or anything like that - there's no turn to wait for! Snoozers losers, you've got loot and levels to find.

From the [original rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf):

> ### Items – Using Them
>
> Any one-shot Item can by played during any combat,
>   whether you have it in your hand or on the table. (Some
>   one-shot Items, such as the **Wishing Ring**, may also be used
>   outside of combat.)

There are no other constraints, and no "you can only play it when the other players say it's OK or are done talking."

As for Curses in particular, remember:

> Curse cards may be played on any player at any time. ANY time, do you hear me?

Answer (score 2):

Also, don't forget you don't have to wait all that long for them to decide what to do, version 1.6 clearly states:

> When you kill a monster, you must wait a reasonable time, *defined as about 2.6 seconds*, for anyone else to speak up. After that, you really have killed the monster [...] though they can still whine and argue.

So go ahead and kill it while they discuss, you'll either force them into making a mistake, or get the treasure ;)

Comment: Take note, the official Munchkin FAQ regards 2.6 as a joke--it is meant as a jab at those people who have a hard time with ambiguity.  Cited from the [FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/):

"`Q. My friends start counting 2.6 seconds as soon as they turn over a monster and combat begins. That's not even enough time to read the card! Is this legal?`: `A.  The rule says you must get "a reasonable time" to respond when another player is winning a fight.  ...  The "2.6 seconds" part of the rule is a joke;`"

Comment: Yes, I realised it's a joke, but it's a useful joke designed to keep the game moving none the less: If they are still discussing what to do 2 minutes after you killed the monster, that's not a reasonable time ;)